# How to guarantee that the template class member is correctly freed when this member is a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

There is a template class A:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    T t;
    A(T t) {
        this->t = t;
        cout << "A constructor" << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "A destructor" << endl;
    }
};
```

t is the member of class A, what if t is a pointer points to dynamically allocated memory so that the default destructor can't free it, for example:

```
A<SomeType*> a(new SomeType());
```

Because we don't know if t is a pointer or not, so we can't just make the deconstructor like this:

```
~A() {
    delete t;
    cout << "A destructor" << endl;
}
```

My question is how to guarantee that there is no memory leak no matter t is a pointer or not

Comment: `A` should not be responsible for de-allocating memory that it didn't allocate. Read up on [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three (if you still choose to implement it your way) and it's *destructor*, not *deconstructor*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `T` is a *raw pointer* then, in "Modern C++", you should assume that it doesn't own the memory location it points to. If you need ownership semantics, you should use *smart pointers* like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` - those clean up after themselves and can be trivially used as `T` without changing `A`.

If you have *raw pointer* that you have no control upon and *owns* some memory, then you should wrap it inside a *smart pointer* before passing it to `A`.

tl;dr: **`T` needs to take care of its own resources and you should assume it does.**